# Query the firebase data to limit the amount of listitems in firebase recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to limit the data number of nodes displayed in firebase when a particular value is reached.

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("questions");
```

This is how my database is stored.

```
users
 ->uid
    ->questions
      ->745
      ->746
      ->747
      ->748
```

Now, I have to show data only before the 747 i.e. just 745 and 746 using the firebaserecycleradapter and I'm unable to understand how can I limit it till 747 only.

I tried using this query but this would just show one item in the list.

```
query = databaseReference.orderByKey().equalTo(number);
```

What could be the possible way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can set your limit with these queries

**.endAt()**

**startAt()**

```
query = databaseReference.orderByKey().endAt(number);
```

and if you want Just Limited count you can use

**limitToFirst()**

or

**limitToLast()**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a Firebase query.

Visit this [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query), it has all the related commands.

You can use `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()`.